# Creating a separate object for each iteration of for-loop within a function

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I have a function that contains a for-loop that iterates 160 times, producing a 3-dimensional array after every iteration. I want the for-loop to save each array separately as object under the name, such as `array001`, `array002`, `array003`, etc., preferably without spitting those out to global workspace. Finally, I want to be able to call some of these arrays later on within the same function.

```
array.function <- function(df, parameter = 0) {
                      for (i in 1:160) {
                           DO A LOT OF STUFF
                           SAVE OUTPUT AS array###
                      }

                      DO MORE STUFF with arrays generated by for-loop above
                   }
```

Any ideas on how to save the arrays as objects with corresponding numbers in its' names? Thank you!

Comment: Put each array into separate element of a list. Then return the list. Something like `myList[[i]] <- array.function(df, i)` or whatever. You could add names with `paste` `myList[[paste0("array", i)]] <- ...`.

Comment: Thanks. Although in this case I would have to append the arrays to the list that is internal to the function and then index the list elements further down the function after for-loop finishes populating the list. I am assuming this is what you meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from [lmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4895725/lmo) is a great workable solution for storing the arrays and accessing them later in the function. However, if you really want them to be stored as separate variables instead of as a list, `assign()` and `get()` are your friends:

```
array.function <- function(df, parameter = 0) {
  # This stores the function's environment for convenience:
  env <- environment()
  for ( i in 1:160 ) { # Then for each iteration
    # make an array and store it in the function's environment
    assign(paste0('array', i), array(c(i, 2:27), dim=c(3, 3, 3)))
  }
  # Then print out a randomly selected array to make sure it worked
  print(get(paste0('array', sample(1:160, 1))))
  # I don't know what you want to do with the arrays,
  # for now just return the whole function's environment
  # (the arrays as well as 'i', 'df', 'env', and 'parameter')
  return(as.list(sapply(ls(envir=env), get, envir=env)))
}

x <- array.function(1) # the 1 is just because I kept your arguments

, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  158    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   10   13   16
[2,]   11   14   17
[3,]   12   15   18

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   19   22   25
[2,]   20   23   26
[3,]   21   24   27
```

For each iteration of your loop, `assign(paste0('array', i), value)` creates a variable in the function's environment -- not the global environment, at least not by default -- whose name is the result of `paste0('array', i)` and whose value is `value` (whatever array you create). You can access it later using `get(paste0('array', x))`, where `x` is the number of the array you need.

An excellent resource for learning more about function environments is [Hadley Wickham's book](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html#function-envs).

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I didn't end up using the environment setup, as it proved to be redundant, just as you had mentioned.